# Middle-button click-and-drag trackpad vs. mouse weirdness

Tags: mouse, redhat-enterprise-linux, touchpad

I am running RHEL 8.9 on a Dell Precision 7560 laptop with a built-in 3-button trackpad (left, middle and right buttons all situated between the trackpad and front edge of the laptop). I have a gtk3 app which needs to read and process middle-button click-and-drag events. The app works fine when I use the trackpad's middle-button, but does NOT work when I use an external 3-button mouse. (The external mouse's middle-button is confirmed as working on another system, and I also tried a second external mouse which failed, too.) When I depress and hold the trackpad middle-button while moving the mouse cursor via either the trackpad or the mouse, the cursor on the display moves as expected and all works fine in my app, whereas the display cursor does NOT move with the external mouse middle-button drag and my app sees no motion events. Simple middle-button click-and-releases on the external mouse, however, work fine. I have tried running with each of the various display servers (X11 vs. Wayland, Classic vs. Unclassic(?), etc.) but they all behave the same here.

I tried debugging with xev and saw exactly what you would expect using the trackpad middle-button, i.e., a Button Press, then a bunch of MotionNotifys, then a ButtonRelease. When I try external mouse middle-button click-and-drag, the initial depress and hold on the middle button causes no event, the subsequent drag generates a ButtonPress/Release event pair every time I would expect to see a MotionNotify event, and finally when the button is released no event is reported.

If the above behavior was not strange enough, the cherry on top is the inverse behavior of at least two different terminal apps (gnome-terminal and xfce4-terminal) in this regard. External mouse middle-click-and-drag will cause the terminal window contents to scroll (i.e., motion events are somehow being passed to the terminals), although again the display cursor does not move. Trackpad middle-click-and-drag, however, does not scroll the terminal window contents although the display cursor moves.

I poked around a bit with xinput but discovered no devices or device properties that would seem to have any obvious impact:

```
% xinput --list
 Virtual core pointer                           id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                 id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ↳ xwayland-pointer:17                        id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:17               id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
 Virtual core keyboard                          id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
   ...  
        
% xinput --list-props xwayland-pointer:17
Device 'xwayland-pointer:17':
        Device Enabled (121):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (123): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        Device Accel Profile (247):     0
        Device Accel Constant Deceleration (248):       1.000000
        Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (249):       1.000000
        Device Accel Velocity Scaling (250):    10.000000
```

It does seem a bit strange to me that I see nothing in the xinput device list that seems to clearly indicate distinct trackpad and mouse devices.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? I want to work with an external mouse and a closed laptop. I have googled a few similar situations on this site and elsewhere but found no solution that would seem to apply to me. The laptop does not have a pointing stick and I have created no shortcuts in ~/.config of which I am aware.

Thanks!